# How to change combobox value / index using keyboard bind with TkInter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have combo box which is created using Tkinter in Python. I want to change / select the combo box index when I press certain key on my keyboard and run the callback function which is bound to the combobox.

```
self.myComboBox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.myFunction)
```

For example : When I press <kbd>1</kbd>, I want the combo box to point to the first index and run the function, when I press <kbd>2</kbd>, I want the combo box to point to the second index and run the function and so on.

Using simple key binding like this doesn't work, it will set the index directly to 1 without capturing any keyboard event

```
self.parent.bind("1", self.myComboBox.current(1))
```

How could I do that? Thanks

Comment: `self.parent.bind("1", lambda e: self.myComboBox.current(0))`. Note that you should pass index 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @HenryYik thank you, your method works for changing the combo box index. But I can't get the value of the selected index. The callback function that is bound to `<<ComboboxSelected>>` is not called

Comment: Do you mean the callback `<<ComboboxSelected>>` is not fired when you press `1`?

Comment: @HenryYik yes, it only changes the index but doesn't execute the callback function

Comment: That is expected - you are not actually "selecting" the combobox, but programmatically changing the selection. Why don't just create a function to run `self.myFunction` at the same time when you press `1`?

Comment: maybe assing to `1` function which changes selected element and runs callback.

Comment: @HenryYik Yes I guess I have no other way other than create separate function for each key. I hope there's a more simple solution which I don't  have to make separate functions for each key, only use the original callback function

Comment: You can generalize it or use a `dict` to map it to the corresponding function. If you intended to have the callback fired upon key press, it should work just the same by passing the index to your new function.

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you, I solved it by just creating 1 function that will accept the combo box index (keyboard key) as parameter